# How to mask treepanel until loading success

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I define a treepanel. And i try add mask() for waiting tree is loading done. But not working.

Here is my code

```
Ext.define('Example.example', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.example',
    title: 'example',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    ...
    listeners: {
        'load': function (store, records, success) {
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('example').getEl().unmask(); // not working
        },
        'beforeload': function (store, options) {                                    
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('example').getEl().mask();// not working
        }
    }
})
});
```

How to make that working thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EIther use the undocumented `ownerTree` property:

```
beforeload: function() {
    this.ownerTree.getEl().mask("Loading", 'x-mask-loading');
}
```

Or register your listeners in a method in order to get the scope:

```
Ext.define('Example.example', {
    // ...
    ,initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.getStore().on({
            scope: this
            ,beforeload: function() {
                this.getEl().mask("Loading", 'x-mask-loading');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I get error like ` this.ownerTree.getEl(...) is undefined` :(

Comment: That means your store starts to load after the listener has been registered, but before the tree panel is rendered... Wrap the call with `if (this.ownerTree.rendered) { ... }` in order to avoid the error.

Comment: If you want the tree masked during the initial loading, you should also add a listener on the tree's render event with something like `if (this.store.isLoading()) { this.getEl().mask() }`.

Comment: it's very nice but mask is not in center, plz view my example code http://jsfiddle.net/KBfQa/ in real my window have some other panel and it's same problem

Comment: You're right. Use the `afterlayout` event instead of `render` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

try this one `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('example').body.mask();` use body instead of `getEl()`

Comment: i try that but get error like `Ext.ComponentQuery.query(...).body is undefined`

Comment: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('example')` returns you and object yes?

Comment: i test by using `alert(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('example'));` in `beforeload` function and get blank alert ?

Comment: console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('example')) prints anything?